# R: excluding rows with a preset list of values in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, extract, subset, rows

I have a data frame that is very large but very similar to this:

```
df <- data.frame(Group = rep(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), 50),
                 Number = sample(1:100, 200, replace = T))

Group   Number
A   52
B   74
C   22
D   90
A   7
B   93
C   50
D   10
A   31
B   19
```

I have another data frame named "remove" that looks like this:

```
>remove
 Group  Number
    A   52
    C   22
    B   93
    D   10
```

How can I subset the df data so I exclude all rows with the Group and Number values in "remove" to get the following data frame? The file is very large so I would be unable to manually type in the values I want to exclude.
Desired output:

```
Group   Number
B   74
D   90
A   7
C   50
A   31
B   19
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with `%in%`

```
df <- df[!(df$Number %in% remove$Number),]
```

`%in%` will return `TRUE` if `df$Number` is in the vector `remove`.  Since we want the complement, we negate the set first with `!`.

Comment: thank you, but what if my "remove" data set also had a Group column. How can I set the Group and Number values in "remove"  to be excluded from df based on Group and Number?

Comment: I edited the code to reflect that.  You just need to look at the column from `remove` with the values you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

For more complex exclusions you could create a unique column in both dataframes (ie Group+Number) and seek to exclude that as per the method described by Christopher.